# How to get file name of the *.docx file in a folder with largest file size?

Tags: batch-file

A directory contains one or more Microsoft Word document files (*.docx). I want to get the file name of the MS Word file with largest file size and store it in a variable.

For example:

```
D:\file1.docx       257 KB
D:\file2.docx       850 KB
D:\file3.docx       122 KB
```

There are three *.docx files with `file2.docx` having largest file size with 850 KB and of which name should be assigned to an environment variable.

Which batch file code is required to achieve this task for above example?

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please provide a [mcve] of your coding attempts! Regard that this site is not a free code writing service, nor is it a tutorial site, it is a question and answer resource for programming-related issues. Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Answer (score 0):

Try this batch file:

```
@echo off
pushd "D:\"

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.docx /A-D /B /O-S 2^>nul') do (
    if "%CD:~-1%" == "\" ( set "FileName=%CD%%%I" ) else set "FileName=%CD%\%%I"
    set "FileSize=%%~zI"
    goto OutputData
)

echo Could not find any *.docx in folder: "%CD%"
popd
goto :EOF

:OutputData
echo "%FileName%" is largest *.docx with file size: %FileSize%
popd
```

The batch file first sets `D:\` has current directory with pushing the path of current directory on stack.

Next **FOR** executes in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in background the command line:

```
dir *.docx /A-D-H /B /O-S 2>nul
```

**DIR** searches in current directory for

- non-hidden files because of `/A-D-H` (attribute not directory and not hidden)
- matching the wildcard pattern `*.docx`
- and outputs in bare format just file name with extension, but without path because of `/B`
- all found files orderer by size with largest file first because of `/O-S`.

The error message output by **DIR** on finding no *.docx file is redirected from handle **STDERR** to device **NUL** with `2>nul` to suppress this error message. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The output of **DIR** to handle **STDOUT** in separate command process is captured by **FOR** and processed next line by line.

**FOR** ignores empty lines and lines starting with a semicolon. By using option `eol=|` the end of line character is modified from `;` to a vertical bar which can't exist at beginning of a file name in comparison to a semicolon which a file name could have as first character.

**FOR** splits up each captured line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab character as string delimiters. A file name can contain one or more spaces. By using option `delims=` an empty list of delimiters is set and so the processed line with file name is not split up at all.

`%CD%` expands to current directory path not ending with a backslash, except the current directory is the root directory of a drive. For that reason the current directory path is concatenated without or with an additional backslash with the file name and file extension of the Microsoft Word file output first by **DIR** on processing first captured line with name of file of largest *.docx file assigned to loop variable `I` .

The **FOR** loop is exited immediately with a jump to label `OutputData` after having full qualified file name assigned to environment variable `FileName` and the file size of this file to environment variable `FileSize`.

Before finally exiting processing of batch file the path of initial current directory is popped from stack and set again as current directory.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `set /?`